# .NET 6 websocket performance

Tags: websocket, .net-6.0

I recently upgraded a .net core 3.1 app to .net 6 and was rather surprised by how much more efficient it seems to be. The application's purpose is to basically send some one-way notifications to client code via a websocket it holds on to in a concurrent dictionary. This app is deployed on k8s, and we typically see load of around 1000 or so websockets on each pod. While running on 3.1, if you checked the count of websockets in the concurrent dictionary it basically matched the number of network connections to the pod, which makes sense. However now in .net 6, it doesn't match at all. In fact it shows about 5 to 8 or so active network connection per pod now. It seems like .net 6 somehow maybe multiplexes websocket connections (or something similar)? I am having trouble figuring out what exactly has changed that so drastically reduced both network connection and request time per connection, and while the performance gains are nice, my network ops team keeps asking me why its "broken" and I have no explanation. Here's quick screen grab i took during deployment. You can see network connections goes from ~1000 per pd to almost none. Can anyone point me in the direction of any docs or anything that explain what changed?[image]

Comment: Interesting. How do you use websockets exactly? The same way it's here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Yes, pretty much exactly that. No SignalR, just using the websocket middleware.